# Sql swapp value of minutes and month

Tags: sql, oracle

While inserting and updating a table using java i have accidentally mixed up minute and month values. Now i have entries in my table like:

```
end_date
12.01.2016 00:05:00
27.01.2017 00:09:00
16.01.2010 00:07:00
```

I can trunc the time part using :

```
UPDATE myTable
SET end_date = trunc(end_date)
WHERE someCondition;
```

which gives me

```
12.01.2016 00:00:00
27.01.2017 00:00:00
16.01.2010 00:00:00
```

but before i do that i want to replace the month value with the minute value, so that i finally have :

```
12.05.2016 00:00:00
27.09.2017 00:00:00
16.07.2010 00:00:00
```

How can i do this?

Comment: How is the data stored in the database (as a string or date)?  If as a date, then many of the values will be invalid.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Data type of end_date  is Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is a date -- and the dates are valid in both directions -- then probably the simplest way is to go back and forth to strings:

```
update myTable
    set end_date = to_date(to_char(end_date, 'DD.MI.YYYY'), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
    where . . .;
```